# Concurrent execution of scheduled tasks in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, timer, scheduling

I have a *TimerTask* that is designed to gather metrics at a specific interval. However it is possible that the period of the task execution is less than the time of task execution (occasionally if something times out and gets delayed).

Is there a way to execute multiple TimerTasks or Runnables, threads, etc. concurrently without waiting for the previous task to complete?

I know that Timer uses a single thread, and the *ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor* will delay execution regardless of the rate.

Thanks.

Comment: So can you explain more concrete why `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(..)` doesn't suit your needs?

Comment: According to the API and from my tests using it... _"If any execution of this task takes longer than its period, then subsequent executions may start late, but will not concurrently execute."_ from [Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you using `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` or `newCachedThreadPool(ThreadFactory threadFactory)` with your own thread factory, in conjuction with Timer. So the code should look like this

```
Executor executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
Timer time = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

    public void run() {
        executor.execute(new Runnable() {

             public void run() {
                  //your business logic
             }
        });
    }
}, delay, period);
```

This way you would schedule tasks with some period and they would all run concurrently.

Comment: That got it...Thanks! If someone could explain how this works as opposed the Timer method or the Scheduler method I would appreciate the knowledge. Essentially how this gets around the blocking.

Comment: The reason is that timer has it's own thread and the only thing this thread does is dispatching tasks to `CachedThreadPool`, which then just run almost every new task in a separate thread. I hope I expained clearly :) You can ask more if you didn't understood something

Comment: Ok apparently this didnt work...I have no clue what's going on...I used the code above, and it seems that if thread B finishes before thread A, then the timer "catches up" and fires other threads in rapid succession.  I looked at the timestamp on my runnables and I had upwards of 14 objects all with the same timestamp.  At this point I'm at a loss.

Comment: Have you tried using custom ThreadFactory in `Executors.newCachedThreadPool(ThreadFactory threadFactory)`? This factory can be really as simple as 

`class SimpleThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory {
   public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
     return new Thread(r);
   
 }}`

Answer (score 0):

Use any Timer implementation, including ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor, but let your timer task do not execute your business logic, but instead quickly start another task (to a cached thread pool, or on its own newly created thread) which actually does heavy computations.