# Counting down two values concurrently using timers

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, timer

I want to countdown two values concurrently using timers. I tried using the methods shown in [here] [Concurrent execution of scheduled tasks in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17822577/concurrent-execution-of-scheduled-tasks-in-java)

```
public class GUI_Time extends javax.swing.JFrame {

int a = 10000; // coundown values
int b = 10000; // countdwon values

private gui_bus_serial server;

/** Creates new form GUI */
public GUI_Time() {

    initComponents();
    jLabel13.setText("---------------------------------");
    jLabel14.setText("---------------------------------");
    Timer(); 
    Timer2();
}
```

First Method/Timer for input "AAA". The timer here will start when input "AAA" is received

```
public final void Timer(){

final Executor executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
Timer time = new Timer();
time.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

@Override
public void run() {
    executor.execute(new Runnable() {

         @Override
         public void run() {
```

The inputs "AAA" and "BBB" will be detected from another GUI and stored into a database. The method show_ID() is to extract the input from the database. The same is goes for method show_ID2().

```
    show_ID();

   //Input "AAA" starts the timer in this method but stops the timer from the second method

    if (ID1.substring(0,3).equals("AAA")){


                 a--;

                 jLabel14.setText(Integer.toString(a));

    }//end of If

         }
    });
}
}, 1000, 1000);

}
```

Second Method/Timer for input "BBB". Timer here starts once input "BBB" is received.

```
public final void Timer2(){

final Executor executor2 = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
Timer time2 = new Timer();
time2.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

@Override
public void run() {
    executor2.execute(new Runnable() {

         @Override
         public void run() {

    show_ID2();

    //Input "BBB" starts the timer in this method but stops the timer from the first method

    if (ID12.substring(0,3).equals("BBB")){ 

                 b--;

                 jLabel13.setText(Integer.toString(b));

    }//end of If

         }
    });
}
}, 1000, 1000);

}
```

Once the input "AAA" or "BBB" is received, I can countdown the values separately but not concurrently.

For example, if input "AAA" is received then countdown from first timer starts. However, the countdown for the first timer stops if the input "BBB" is received.

I think its due to the if statements inside the first and second methods.

Its there any method which I can try to make it run concurrently ?

Thank you

Comment: Please describe what are the `show_ID(), show_ID2()` methods doing, and also where are `ID1` and `ID12` modified. And have in mind that even if you manage to run both timers concurrently, you are not going to count seconds. Thats not how you count, because threads are preempted and there's no guarantee they are run at 1 second interval. And even if they did, those string operations consume extra time as well, time you are counting as if it were inside that second.

Comment: And even if you had a single thread in your app scheduled to run each second and doing nothing in the `run` method, it still wont run each second since the JVM process might be preempted by the OS as well.

Comment: The inputs "AAA" and "BBB" will be detected from another GUI and stored into a database. The method show_ID() is to extract the data which is either "AAA" or "BBB" from the database. The same is goes for method show_ID2(). Is it because of Timer and Timer2 not running concurrently could be the reason why the timers stop if the another input is detected ?

Comment: You could set a breakpoint in the `run` method of boths timers and check what's happening. Unless your code were some kind of experiment, I won't advise doing time-consuming stuff like reading from a DB in a timer that has to update GUI, it might block

Comment: *Don’t mix up* `java.util.Timer` *with* `javax.swing.Timer`! When you want to modify the GUI from the timer (as you do) you *must use* `javax.swing.Timer`.